# A definite integral involving powers and logs

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

The following integral is known

$\int_0^1x^{\mu-1}(1-x^r)^{v-1}ln(x)dx=\frac{1}{r^2}B(\frac{\mu}{r},v)[\psi(\frac{\mu}{r})-\psi(\frac{\mu}{r}+v)]$

I am trying to calculate some inequality measures and keep facing the following integral.

$\int_0^1x^{\mu-1}(1-x^r)^{v-1}ln(1-x)dx$

Is there a similar solution to this? Someone has asked about this integral several years ago but no closed form solution has been given.

Comment: A formula for the case $r = 1$ can be be derived from the known integral using the substitution $x \mapsto 1 - x$.

Answer (score 2):

**PARTIAL ANSWER**

If you make use of the Maclaurin expansion of $ln(1-x)$ and then proceed with the substitution $u=1-x^r$ you'll arrive at this infinite series
$$-\frac{1}{r} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}B(υ,\frac{μ+n}{r}).$$
From there, apply the series expansion for the beta function, in particular:
$$B(x,y)=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{(1-x)_m}{(y+m)m!},$$
where $(x)_m$ is the rising factorial. Then by an interchange of series, followed by the use of a formula for the digamma function:
$$ψ(z+1)=-γ+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{z}{n(n+z)},$$
you'll have that
$$\int_{0}^{1}x^{μ-1}(1-x^r)^{υ-1}ln(1-x)dx=-\frac{1}{r}B(υ,\frac{μ}{r})-\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{(1-υ)_m}{(μ+rm)m!}ψ(μ+rm+1).$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there a closed form solution that does not involve infinite series?